# Bash startup scrips in OSX for MESA_STAR setup

Tags: bash, macos

I need to install and run the MESA STAR stellar evolution package as per the instructions on this page: http://mesa.sourceforge.net/prereqs.html. I already have everything I need downloaded and in the right place in my system. However, I have very little experience setting up startup scripts, so I'm not entirely sure how to follow the rest of the instructions on the page. If someone could point me towards which files I need to edit such that the commands

```
export MESA_DIR=/Users/myname/Software/mesar9575
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
export MESASDK_ROOT=/Applications/mesasdk
export $MESASDK_ROOT/bin/mesasdk_init.sh
```

run each time I open a new shell, I would be very thankful. I think this should be possible, but I have no idea how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Terminal.app` then edit `~/.bash_profile` and add:

```
export MESA_DIR=/Users/myname/Software/mesar9575
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
export MESASDK_ROOT=/Applications/mesasdk
export $MESASDK_ROOT/bin/mesasdk_init.sh
```

Save the file, then from the shell prompt:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

That should be all you need to complete the process. If you are running a different shell than the default `OS X`, [look here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abdy) for a listing of profiles and their associated shells.